# How to reuse a flyout menu on WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a project where I've lot a few diferent listview/gridviews itemstemplate.
yet all share the same flyout menu, something like this

```
  <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout >
            <MenuFlyout >


                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Uid="lbl_action_sheet_title_add_to_playlist" Text="$add to playlist" />
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Uid="lbl_action_sheet_share" Text="$share" />

            </MenuFlyout>
        </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
```

And I want to reuse it not copy paste it to N templates

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an attached behavior to attach the menu from a `DataTemplate` resource.

Comment: Can you give an example it's the first time I hear about that possibility